# matlab - Error loading from installed third-party toolbox

Tags: matlab, toolbox

OK, I'm fairly new to the Matlab, and it's first time installing a custom toolbox. I'm using Matlab R2015a on 64-bit Windows machine and tried to install third-party [toolbox](http://iristoolbox.codeplex.com/). I used **addpath C:\WhereToolboxUnpacked** and then **savepath**

**ver** call shows that Toolbox is installed, however Matlab seem to cannot find a function from it! Simple example from [here](http://iristoolbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Five-Minute%20Introduction%20to%20IRIS&referringTitle=Home) gives an error:

```
Undefined function 'model' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in run_my_model (line 10)
m = model('my_simple_rbc.model');
```

**help model** returns

```
help for xregdesign/model
```

It seems that this model is not from my installed toolbox.

Comment: Did you run the startup command?

Comment: No, i've not. Could you please elaborate? I'm new to Matlab. Console writes startup not found, and toolbox site writes nothing about startup file.

Comment: http://iristoolbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Download%20and%20Install%20IRIS&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Thanks! Overlooked that part.